# Reimplementing to_i with pack/unpack

Tags: ruby

I re-implemented `String#to_i` to use bytes to store individual characters. My solution is:

```
def to_i(string)
  string.bytes.map { |ascii| ascii - 48 }.inject { |sum, int| sum * 10 +  int}
end

to_i("22") # => 22
```

I was wondering if it was possible to implement `to_i` with `pack` and `unpack` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the only thing `pack`/`unpack` can do here is convert the digit string into array of numbers. Besides, the implementation is buggy. It didn't check whether the input is really digit string.

```
def to_i(string)
  string.unpack('C*').reduce(0){|sum, i| sum * 10 + i - 48}
end
```